# Тестовое задание на junior frontend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Я пытаюсь устроиться на позицию junior frontend разработчик и одна из компаний прислала мне тестовое задание. Оно показалось мне странным из-за объема, но изначально я решила, что у меня просто недостаток опыта. Суть задания в том, чтобы разработать файловый клиент, api у них нет, поэтому сказали крутиться через firebase.Попросила на него две недели, но усомнилась и через пару дней написала hr, что 2 недели на тестовое это много. На это она ответила, что их кандидаты выполняют это за 4 дня. Подскажите пожалуйста, должен ли junior делать подобное за 4 дня и стоит ли браться за такие большие тестовые? Буду очень благодарна за ответ! Оставляю ссылку на полное тестовое https://spiky-sky-d11.notion.site/frontend-web-cloud-storage-client-fa687ddac81d4088a2e1e4ca6dd499f1.
На всякий случай:
[[image: 1 часть задания][1]]

Comment: Скорее всего тут имеется в виду, что нужно хранить данные о файловой структуре, файлах (ссылки) в БД, а сами файлы возможно в хранилище (например S3).

Comment: Чёт это больше на backend вакансию похоже..

Comment: Кажется ищут одаренных джунов, которые будут пахать как фуллстак чисто за стаж и тестовое проверяет потяните ли вы это :)